# how to use ILogger when using global ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-core

i have an action filter where i am trying to log name of action that system enters and left.

```
         public class LogFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
        {
            private readonly ILogger<LogFilter > _logger;
            public LogFilter(ILogger<LogFilter > logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
            } 
            public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
            {

                _logger.LogInformation("Entering " + context.ActionDescriptor.ToString());
                // execute any code before the action executes
                var result = await next();
                // execute any code after the action executes
                _logger.LogInformation("Exiting " + context.ActionDescriptor.ToString());
            }
        }
```

but when i have to register this action Filter globally

```
 services.AddControllers(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new LogFilter (how to pass ilogger));
        });
```

what should i pass in the constructor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raas, You can add this filter by type. It works for me.

```
services.AddControllers(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(typeof(LogFilter)); // add filter By type
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this:

```
services.AddControllers(config =>
    {
        config.Filters.Add<LogFilter>();
    });
```

Comment: I'm not certain this is _better_, per se. But it is slightly _shorter_, at least.